# Problems with starting the emulator in Windows

Tags: android-emulator

I started a project of developing a rather simple app, and it was working with the emulator, although it was taking time to start the first time. But now, for some reason, I cannot have the emulator starting properly anymore. The window opens up, with the title 5554:AVD_for_Nexus_5..... but the display remains blank forever. Nothing ever happens. The only change I was trying to do was to enable navigation keys such a back, home, etc.

Comment: Try recreating the AVD.

Comment: I tried and had the same problem. However, when I re-created the same vm (Nexus 7 2012) as I used when first developing my app (as opposed as a different model (Nexus 5) ). I am going to retry ona different system for the Nexus 5. Maybe the problem is with the binary image of the Nexus 5 itself.